# url showing page with and without .htm

Tags: url, ubuntu, alias

Stumped with this one. Found out through Google webmaster tools that a .htm page on my website can be accessed either by {page} or {page}.htm. it is {page}.htm as a static file and i built the server from scratch so i know there is no rewrites or apache configs that are doing AFAIK. Ubuntu 10.04.

Any suggestions?

A page in question is:

http://www.hello-grancanaria.co.uk/accommodation/balito-beach-2387

try adding the .htm on the end.

regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it!

Apparently, its the work of MultiViews. Simply delete this from the apache conf file and now the link without the .htm is not found. Perfect.